# Mapbox custom user location image

Tags: ios, mapbox

I'm using **Mapbox 2.1.2** where I need to set a custom image for the user location annotation. This is not a problem to implement both in MapKit or GoogleMaps but how do I deal with this using Mapbox?

If this is not possible, how can I track the user's location? I've already tried to add MGLPointAnnotation objects on location update. But then I have to have a cache of annotations and clear it on adding a new, most recent one which also leads to a "flash" ugly effect.

Comment: Additionally to the answer of Minh Nguyễn I give a full customisation example code in my other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43266706/1495892

Answer (score 2):

Background on customizing the user location annotation: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/2272

The best way to do this right now is to follow the guidance there, which is to customize the `MGLUserLocationAnnotation` class in the source code (the SDK is open source).

Answer (score 2):

As of Mapbox iOS SDK v3.4.0, you can provide your own user location annotation view that contains a UIImageView. In your MGLMapViewDelegate, implement the [`-mapView:viewForAnnotation:`](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.4.1/Protocols/MGLMapViewDelegate.html#/c:objc%28pl%29MGLMapViewDelegate%28im%29mapView:viewForAnnotation:) method to check whether the `annotation` is equal to the MGLMapView’s `userLocation`; if so, return a new [MGLUserLocationAnnotationView](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.4.1/Classes/MGLUserLocationAnnotationView.html) that contains a UIImageView. There’s a work-in-progress example of customizing the user dot in [this pull request](https://github.com/mapbox/ios-sdk-examples/pull/50).