# Swift 3 - Mapbox - Customize User Location Annotation

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I'm Looking to change the appearance of the users location annotation. I understand this is now possible using `MGLUserLocationAnnotationView`, however, I'm unsure how to implement this. Can anyone provide a simple example of how this is done?

Thanks

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40279217/1072229) help?

Comment: I was looking more for a concrete example.

Comment: That answer did link to an example, `MGLFaux3DUserLocationAnnotationView`. The `.h` and `.m` files there seem to be a full implementation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are right. The MapBox API [MGLUserLocationAnnotationView](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.4.0/Classes/MGLUserLocationAnnotationView.html) description is very short. The user location view customisation is available since MapBox iOS SDK 3.4.0. [See also the feature comments on the MapBox  GitHub](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/pull/5573)

It is important to note: The MGLUserLocationAnnotationView is a subclass of the MGLAnnotationView. It means the MGLUserLocationAnnotationView acts just like a normal annotation view.

Here is an example how to customise the user location view. Create a new class (e.g. CustomUserLocationAnnotationView) and override a layoutSubviews() to add a custom code. In this example I use an UIImage UserLocationIcon.png to visualise the user position on the map.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Mapbox

final class CustomUserLocationAnnotationView: MGLUserLocationAnnotationView {
    override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // Force the annotation view to maintain a constant size when the map is tilted.
        scalesWithViewingDistance = false

        layer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
        layer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityCenter

        // Use your image here
        layer.contents = UIImage(named: "UserLocationIcon")?.cgImage
    }
}
```

In your UIViewController or whatever else (e.g. Service class) implement the MGLMapViewDelegate with at least two functions -mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:
 and -mapView:viewForAnnotation:. See my comments inline:

```
extension ViewController: MGLMapViewDelegate {
    // Wait until the map is loaded before proceed with other actions on map
    func mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap(_ mapView: MGLMapView) {
        // Show the user location here
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, viewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView? {
        // Customise the user location annotation view
        if annotation is MGLUserLocation {
            var userLocationAnnotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "CustomUserLocationAnnotationViewIdentifier") as? CustomUserLocationAnnotationView

            if userLocationAnnotationView == nil {
                userLocationAnnotationView = CustomUserLocationAnnotationView(reuseIdentifier: "CustomUserLocationAnnotationViewIdentifier")
            }

            // Optional: You can save the annotation object for later use in your app
            self.userLocationAnnotation = annotation

            return userLocationAnnotationView
        }

        // Customise your annotation view here...

        return customAnnotationView
    }
}
```

The MapView -mapView:viewForAnnotation: delegate function is called for every annotation view instance including the user annotation view.

**Optionally:** To get your CustomUserLocationAnnotationView instance, you can use this function everywhere in your code:

```
    // The userLocationAnnotation was previously saved in your ViewController in the -mapView:viewForAnnotation: delegate function
    let view = mapView.view(for: self.userLocationAnnotation) as? CustomUserLocationAnnotationView
```

Comment: That's weird, my view for annotation doesn't get called when I start user tracking.

Comment: @huggie I also had the same issue, `viewForAnnotation` didn't get called. I figured out that it was because I've set the `mapView` in storyboard and there I've set `ShowUserLocation` to `On`. After setting it to `Default` my `viewForAnnotation` got called. Using `mapView.showsUserLocation` in code works ok.

Comment: @Andrej Thanks this solved the problem for me! Also I had to call `setNeedLayout()` on `CustomUserLocationAnnotationView` for `layoutSubviews()` to be called.

Comment: There’s also now [an official example](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/user-location-annotation/) of how to implement a custom user location annotation view at the Mapbox site.

Comment: Its working nice. But how can I add it to a MGLSymbolStyleLayer? I want to add a camera with pitch and otherwise it has not the right perspective.

Comment: @desmeit Yes, the behaviour of customised user location annotation is different from the original one. It will not tilt (perspective) with camera and no ripple effect.