# Swift Mapbox custom user location annotation(Fatal Error)

Tags: swift, mapbox

I would like to create a custom user location pin which it gets the photoURL from Firebase and displays it. I tried using this [Swift 3 - Mapbox - Customize User Location Annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41796086/swift-3-mapbox-customize-user-location-annotation) as a reference. However, I get an error when I build the custom class. I am not sure can I edit much in the `MGLUserLocationAnnotationView` but it seems like inherit `UIView` so I think it should be fine. Also, should I get the data from Firebase in the View Class or in the View Controller?

**It is my custom class**

```
class CustomUserLocationDisplayView: MGLUserLocationAnnotationView {

  var view: UIView!

  @IBOutlet weak var displayView: UIImageView!
  var imageView: UIImageView!

  required override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    setup()
  }
  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
  }
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("Error")         <--------- I get this FATAL Error
  }

  func readFirebaseUserProfile(){
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    let photoURL = user?.photoURL
      displayView.kf.setImage(with: photoURL)
  }

  func setup() {
    view = loadViewFromNib()
    displayView.layer.cornerRadius = 30
    addSubview(view)
  }

  func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomUserLocationDisplayView", bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

    return view
  }
}
```

**It is my function for annotation**

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, viewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MGLPointAnnotation{

    }else{
        var userLocationAnnotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "user") as? CustomUserLocationDisplayView

        if userLocationAnnotationView == nil {
          userLocationAnnotationView = CustomUserLocationDisplayView(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifer)

        }

        return userLocationAnnotationView
      }
  }
```

Comment: Remove the call to `fatalError` and replace it with proper code.

Comment: @rmaddy I tried but it is required in the subclass of MGLUserLocationAnnotationView

Comment: No, the call to fatalError is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible issue: I don't see where you call `readFirebaseUserProfile`. I would double check that it is being called.

Also, could you put a breakpoint after `if userLocationAnnotationView == nil {` and see if you are reaching it? You could also try something like:

```
 if annotation is MGLUserLocation && mapView.userLocation != nil {
    userLocationAnnotationView = CustomUserLocationDisplayView(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifer)

    return userLocationAnnotationView
 } else if annotation is MGLPointAnnotation {
    // Set annotations here
 }
 return nil
```